# Package offline

Tags: scala, sbt

We have a scala project that use some dependencies:

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1",
"org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0",
"log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.1",
"org.apache.hive" % "hive-jdbc" % "2.1.1"
```

While running build.sbt on a machine with an internet there isn't seems to be a problem but when moving to a machine without internet with an identical copy of ~/.sbt and ~/.ivy2 there are resolve issues with spakr-core and spark-sql (all the rest are OK)

Any suggestion how to solve it and what would be the best option to run sbt offline ? (we got artificatory but when I upload JARS to it, artifactory stores the JARS in a different path than what sbt is looking for)

Thanks

Comment: Would it be feasible to just copy the ivy cache to the disconnected machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put sbt into offline mode:

```
$ sbt "set offline := true" package
```

or at sbt prompt:

```
set offline := true
package
```